# Customising the position of the integral limits

Tags: math-mode

So, I would like to write the following integral:

[image]

by writing

```
\int\limits_{\xi=\cos\cfrac{\pi}{3}}^{\xi=\cos 0}  \xi^2 d \xi
```

(please ignore the \cdot on the left of the image).

However, the lower limit is too low, is there a way to put it a little higher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to simply use `\frac` instead of `\cfrac`. That is,

```
\[ \int\limits_{\xi=\cos\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\xi=\cos 0}  \xi^2 d \xi \]
```

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot that illustrates the output of your answer. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 8):

The only good use of `\cfrac` is for continued fractions. (Hence the name.)

I would like to recommend you use inline-style fraction notation in the lower limit and `1` (since `cos 0 = 1`) in the upper limit. I'd also use `\smashoperator[r]{...}` to snug up the integral symbol to the integrand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\smashoperator' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\int\limits_{\xi=\cos\cfrac{\pi}{3}}^{\xi=\cos 0}  \xi^2 d \xi
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\smashoperator[r]{\int\limits_{\cos\pi/3}^{1}}  \xi^2 \,d\xi
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think using the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` (~80 % of `display style`), combined  with `\smash`, and `\smashoperator` from `mathtools`, will look better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools} %

\begin{document}
\[
\int\limits_{\xi=\cos\cfrac{\pi}{3}}^{\xi=\cos 0} \xi^2\, d \xi
\quad\text{vs.}\quad\int\limits_{\xi=\cos\smash[t]{\mfrac{\pi}{3}}}^{\xi=\cos 0} \xi^2\,d \xi
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]